# Django conditional many-to-many relation exists check

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

The model is:

```
class RecordModel(BaseModel):
    visibility_setting = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    visible_to = models.ManyToManyField(UserModel, blank=True)
```

I need to return rows depending on row `visibility_setting`:

- if `visibility_setting == 0` - return row without any checks,
- if `visibility_setting == 1` - I need to check if user is in `visible_to` m2m relation exists.

In second case query works okay, but in first case my approach of setting `None` on first case not working (*as expected*):

```
Feed.objects.filter(
    visible_to=Case(
        When(visibility_setting=0, then=None),  # no data returned in this case, but I want to 
                                                # return all rows with visibility_setting=0
        When(visibility_setting=1, then=user.id),  # rows with visibility_setting=1 are queried okay
    )
)
```

I am a little bit stuck which way to use in this situation? Can we not apply case at all in some conditions or use some specific default to skip `visible_to` relations check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Feed.objects.filter(Q(visibility_setting=0) | Q(visible_to=my_user)).distinct()
```

the [**`.distinct()`** call <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)
prevents returning the same `Feed` multiple times.

Comment: Nice easy solution, and if you have more visibility_settings values or dont want to use distinct, you can
```Feed.objects.filter(Q(visibility_setting=0) | (Q(visibility_setting=1) & (visible_to=user.id)))```

Comment: @Omkommersind: yes! Or slighly shorter: `Feed.objects.filter(Q(visibility_setting=0) | Q(visibility_setting=1, visible_to=user.id))` :)